# How to set the offset.commit.policy to AlwaysCommitOffsetPolicy in debezium?

Tags: debezium

I created a Debezium Embedded engine to capture MySQL change data. I want to commit the offsets as soon as I can. In the code, the config is created including follows.

`.with("offset.commit.policy",OffsetCommitPolicy.AlwaysCommitOffsetPolicy.class.getName())`

Running this returns, `java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: io.debezium.embedded.spi.OffsetCommitPolicy$AlwaysCommitOffsetPolicy.<init>(io.debezium.config.Configuration)`

However, When I start the embedded engine with,
`.with("offset.commit.policy",OffsetCommitPolicy.PeriodicCommitOffsetPolicy.class.getName())`, the embedded engine works fine.

Note that the class `OffsetCommitPolicy.PeriodicCommitOffsetPolicy` constructor includes the config parameter while `OffsetCommitPolicy.AlwaysCommitOffsetPolicy` doesn't.

`public PeriodicCommitOffsetPolicy(Configuration config) {
...
}`

How to get the debezium embedded engine to use its `AlwaysCommitOffsetPolicy`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the report. This is partly bug (which we would appreciate if you could log into our Jira). You can solve this issue by calling a dedicated method embedded engine builder like  `io.debezium.embedded.EmbeddedEngine.create().with(OffsetCommitPolicy.always())'

Comment: Thanks. `io.debezium.embedded.EmbeddedEngine.create().using(OffsetCommitPolicy.always())` works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Tested with version *1.4.0Final*:

```
new EmbeddedEngine.BuilderImpl() // create builder
        .using(config) // regular config
        .using(OffsetCommitPolicy.always()) // explicit commit policy
        .notifying(this::handleEvent) // even procesor
        .build(); // and finally build!
```